# Why on Ctrl+C my process suddenly stopped on "Task<T>.Result", but works fine with "await Task<T>"?

Tags: c#

Please help to understand what's going on.

I have `async` method. It return `Task<T>`.

I need wait this method result BUT with correct stop by Ctrl+C.

The problem is:

*If I wait in this way - **all works fine**:*

```
      var result = **await Task<T>**
```

*If I wait in this way - **main process suddenly stoped**:*

```
      var result = **Task<T>.Result**
```

To show it in code, I write small test (sorry - I can't make it smaller)

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StopTest4
{
    internal static class ConsoleApp
    {
        private static readonly TaskCompletionSource<bool> GetFirstString = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        private static void OnCancelKeyPressed(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got Stop Signal (by Crt+C)");
            GetFirstString.TrySetResult(false);
            
            args.Cancel = true;
        }

        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var appTask = RunAsync();

                Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancelKeyPressed;

                return appTask.Result;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Got exception while run main task of the App - {e}");
            }

            return -2;
        }
        
        
        private static async Task<int> RunAsync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RunAsync START");
            try
            {
                await LoadWorksFine().ConfigureAwait(false);
                //await LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Got Exception - {e}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped!");
            return 0;
        }

        private static Task LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Befor LoadString");
                var result = LoadString().Result;
                Console.WriteLine($"After LoadString - result=\"{result}\"");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"LOAD: Got Exception - {e}");
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private static async Task LoadWorksFine()
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Befor LoadString");
                var result = await LoadString();
                Console.WriteLine($"After LoadString - result=\"{result}\"");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"LOAD: Got Exception - {e}");
            }
        }

        private static async Task<string> LoadString()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"LoadString: Start");
            try
            {
                if (!await GetFirstString.Task.ConfigureAwait(false))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"LoadString: waited task Failed!");
                    return "false";
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"LoadString: waited task Success!");
                return "true";

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"LoadString: Got Exception - {e}");
            }
            return null;
        }

    } 
}
```

How to check:

If You run the test and press Ctrl+C you will see such output:

```
% dotnet StopTest4.dll
RunAsync START
Befor LoadString
LoadString: Start
^CGot Stop Signal (by Crt+C)                  <---- Here press Ctrl+C
LoadString: waited task Failed!
After LoadString - result="false"
Stopped!
%
```

All works fine!

Now in method `RunAsync` comment `LoadWorksFine()` and uncomment `LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose()`. Like this:

```
    private static async Task<int> RunAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RunAsync START");
        try
        {
            //await LoadWorksFine().ConfigureAwait(false);
            await LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Got Exception - {e}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Stopped!");
        return 0;
    }
```

Now run the test and press Ctrl+C you will see such output:

```
% dotnet StopTest4.dll
RunAsync START
Befor LoadString
LoadString: Start
^C                  <---- Here press Ctrl+C
%
```

**There are no any exceptions or errors - just process stopped.**

It works on MacOS, Linux and Windows.

Who knows why? As for me - both variants correct.

Thank You!

P.S.: I want second variant - I need to call async method in synchronous method.

Comment: `I need to call async method in synchronous method.` Why can't you make the synchronous method asynchronous?

Comment: Because in real code I need to implement event handler, like this:

 **string OnGetString()**

And I can't change delegate - it's in library.

Comment: I don't get the problem, actually. In the question, you mix async and sync - which is a bad idea. And now you reveal that in "real code" you need to mix that with events which is even worse? That's really confusing. Can you please just setup an [mcve] that shows your _real_ problem?

Comment: _"I need to call async method in synchronous method."_ - as the question is right now - I'm not convinced you actually need to.

Comment: Or put differently: What do you actually need to do? What is your real-world problem?

Comment: Real-world problem:

  I got command-socket. It give me command as event with delegate **string OnGetStringReq()**

  I have connection to Server with DB. And I have async Client to the Server.
    
  When I got request - I ask the Server, wait the result and pass to command socket.

It looks like this:

public string OnGetStringReq()
{
   return _client.GetLastStr().Result;
}

And all works fine, till I got Ctrl+C (SigInt) to stop.
On Stop command I must send to Command socket message "Sorry, I am stopping".

CommandSocket - from library. I can't change event delegate.

Comment: Please share [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I post the question on dotnet git.

And got the answer:

> Because your example is synchronously blocking the RunAsync method
> waiting for the handler to be invoked, but by that point you haven't
> hooked up the handler. So when ctrl-C is pressed, there isn't a
> handler to cancel the ctrl-C, and the OS kills the process.

And yes - in this code:

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        var appTask = RunAsync();

        Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancelKeyPressed;

        return appTask.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Got exception while run main task of the App - {e}");
    }

    return -2;
}
```

line `Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancelKeyPressed;` never called.

If put it BEFOR `var appTask = RunAsync();` all works fine in both variants.

But now I don't understand WHY in second variant `Console.CancelKeyPress += OnCancelKeyPressed;` never called.

As I understand, `var appTask = RunAsync();` only create Task.

Task waiting here - `return appTask.Result;`!

WHY `var appTask = RunAsync();` synchronously blocked? It is a TASK...

**UPDATE**
Now I understood!

You call RunAsync:

```
var appTask = RunAsync();
```

RunAsync calls LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose:

```
await LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Note that this is exactly the same as if you'd written:

```
Task t = LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose();
await t.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

meaning you're calling LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose synchronously from RunAsync, and there are no awaits that complete asynchronously prior to it, so your Main method has synchronously invoked LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose. Then LoadWithProcessSuddenlyClose synchronously blocks:

```
var result = LoadString().Result;
```

waiting for the ctrl-C handler to be invoked. You've created a deadlock: you're blocking waiting for something that can only happen after this call returns, because it's only hooked up after this call returns, but this call will never return because it requires the hooked up thing to be invoked to do so.